# Functions continuous at a point

Tags: functions, continuity, absolute-value

Prove that if $ f: R→ R $ is continuous at $ a $, then $ g : x→ |f(x)| $ is also continuous at $a $ . I don't know how to approach this, how is it proved?

Comment: I think this follows directly from the reverse triangle inequality applied to the epsilon-delta definition of continuity.

Comment: Also what do you mean $g : R \rightarrow |f(x)|$? Does $g$ map from the reals to $|f(x)|$ or is that a typo :)

Comment: Sorry it was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

By the triangular inequality,

$$||f(x)|-|f(a)||\le|f(x)-f(a)|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f :R \rightarrow R$ be a continuous function at $a$. Then $\forall \epsilon > 0, \text{ there exists a } \delta $ s.t. $\left|x-c\right|<\delta  \implies \left|f(x)-f(c)\right| < \epsilon$.

Not consider $g(x) = |f(x)|$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. We know by previous definition that there exists a  $\delta$ s.t. $\left|x-c\right|<\delta$ implies $\left|f(x)-f(c)\right| < \epsilon$. By the reverse triangle inequality we have:

$$\Big||f(x)| - |f(c)|\Big| \le |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$$

and therefore $\left|x-c\right|<\delta$ implies $\Big||f(x)| - |f(c)|\Big| < \epsilon$ as required.